# Html5 attributes for side menu

Tags: html

I have a page with the usual suspects on - header, main nav etc.

In the main page I have an article such as terms & conditions, then in the left column an associated menu that can be used to switch between different policies - privacy, cookie policy etc.

From what I've read this is not a use for the nav attrcibute (I could be wrong), but is it then an aside as it does relate to the main content of the page?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: `nav` = navigation. `aside` = content.

Comment: Can you show us your HTML?

Answer (score 1):

My guess:

- you have a main navigation menu
- and a secondary navigation menu, like a submenu, this one
  related to the main content of that page which is placed aside BUT
  related directly to the main content of the page → use nav not
  aside

even if it's placed aside, respectively in the left side, it is not aside content; 
aside tag applies to less relevant content from the relevant content ("relevant content" = the content within your main tag and so is your menu related to this main content)

see [aside](http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/html5_aside_tag.php)  for more infos

Answer (score 1):

I think you sghould use the `nav` element for your main navigation on your site, and other lists of links etc. could be placed in the `menu` element, or simply in an `ul` element.

According to the [HTML 5 specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-nav-element) the `nav` element is primarily intended for sections that consist of major navigation blocks.